# jquery: using two datepicker with two fields ( field 1 , field2 + 1 day ) like booking.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

How r u?

I have two datepickers with two fields

I want when the user choosing **(From)** the second field **( TO )** will be next day . like **booking.com**

for example: when the user choose **From** 01-01-2013 , directly the second field **TO** 02-01-2013 ***(next day)*** ...

### look at this picture for the form

[image]

this is code of jquery:

```
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1D",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
    minDate: "+1D",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true , 

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        var d = dateFormat(new Date(dateText + 1), "DD/MM/YYYY");
        $("#to").val(d);
    }

});
```

this is my html code:

```
<form method="get" action="">
        <input type="submit" value="choose"/>
        <p><input type="text" name="from" id="from" />From<br/>
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to" />To
        </p>
</br>

    </form>
```

***how can do it?***

Comment: `dateText + 1` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I want to add +1 day like this ( 01 - 12 - 2013) , the second field will be ( 02 - 12 - 2013)

Comment: I know what you want to do. But `dateText` is a string, so `dateText + 1` will just append `"1"` to the string: `"01-12-2013"+1` is `"01-12-20131". You need to convert it to a date, then use functions `getDate()` and `setDate()` to change the day.

Comment: aha , I understand what you mean , but how can do it? plz if you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
    var d = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    $("#to").val($.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a working JSFiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/jirilmongeorge/f329k/26/

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1D",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
    minDate: "+1D",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true , 
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        var d = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
        d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
        $("#to").val($.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));
    }

   });

   $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

  $('#from').attr('readonly', true);
  $('#to').attr('readonly', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert your dateText into the right format of date, then plus one and set back to the #to value

```
var from = dateText.split("-");
var fDate = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);

var newdate = new Date(fDate);
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);
$("#to").val(newdate.getDate() + "-" + newdate.getMonth() + "-" + newdate.getFullYear());
```