# Calculate date difference in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is; there are 2 fields in my application, one is date (Field1) and second is a label (Field2). So, I want that when user selects a date in field 1, then field 2 should be automatically populated (current date - date from field 1).
Can anyone help on how to implement it.

I'm using jQuery to display date:

```
// This displays the date dialog when user clicks on Field1
$('#Field1').click(function () {
    $('#Field1').simpleDatepicker();
});

// Tried following code but it didn't worked
$('#Field1').click(function () {
    $('#Field1').simpleDatepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
       $('#Field2').value(calculateDays($('#Field1').toString))
        }
    });
});

function calculateDays(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var inputDate = new Date(dateString);
    var days = today - inputDate;
    return days;
};
```

This may look like pathetic code to some folks but I'm just a beginner, so any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Also please tell me if this can be done using html only and no need to go to jQuery. It is my understanding that the calculating days (difference between dates) code will go in jQuery since this needs to be fired after selecting date ('onSelect' event). Please correct if wrong.

Comment: How is this related to the Model-View-Controller paradigm? This looks like a **jQuery** only question.

Comment: @Jimbo note that using jQuery without any other framework does not necessarily exclude the possibility of using an MVC-style approach in that there are varying degrees to which one can separate concerns…

Comment: @Barney Note that this question is neither related to a framework, what you call an "MVC-style approach", nor any design pattern. It is *solely a jQuery question*, and has been correctly re-tagged as such. Anything unrelated will probably be removed (and so it should be - we're here to keep everything relevant). I'd also like to point out that OP tagged as [tag:c#] and [tag:asp.net], as well as [tag:mvc].

Comment: @Jimbo Sorry, wasn't trying to be critical. I suppose the scope of the example code is too simple to be able to provide an answer that can qualitatively fulfill the 'MVC' requirement.

Comment: ok..this might be a jquery only question but as I mentioned if it's possible to add this in html part (view of MVC) instead of jquery then those suggestions would also be useful. That was one thing for which I added 'mvc' tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're trying to use [Karl Seguin's jquery.simpleDatePicker](https://github.com/karlseguin/jquery.simpleDatePicker) (it came top when searching for "simpledatepicker" on Google).

As Jimbo remarks in the comments, it's hard to advise on an MVC approach here — you say you want to do this purely with HTML, but HTML alone can't dictate behaviour (I'd say that's extremely *un*-MVC). HTML5 forms *do* allow some limited behavioural control (validation etc), and they also offer `<input type="date"/>`, but none of these help your situation.

So for this answer I'm just going to fix the mistakes in your code:

1. The plugin is initialised with the `simpleDatePicker` jQuery method — you forgot to capitalise the 'P';
2. The plugin itself caters for the click event. You should initialise it directly without waiting for user input;
3. There was no `onSelect` initialisation option in the source code: I chose to use a `change` event listener on the input to capture this;
4. You use the jQuery method `value` — that's native DOM Javascript — you should be using `val` instead;
5. `toString` won't work on DOM elements or jQuery objects — again, use the `val` method;
6. The native Date object can't parse dates in arbitrary formats — nor would your code produce a number of days if it did (it would just produce the difference in milliseconds). For this kind of functionality you should use a good date library: I've opted for [Moment](http://momentjs.com/).

Resulting code ([as demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/B6dFG/)):

```
$('#Field1')
    .simpleDatePicker()
    .on('change', function passValue(){
        $('#Field2').val(calculateDaysFromNow($('#Field1').val()))
    });

function calculateDaysFromNow(dateString){
    return moment.duration(moment(dateString,'MMM DD YYYY').diff()).days();
}
```

A bit of elaboration on how I've used moment:

First of all, we want to parse `#Field1`'s formatted date for an actual quantifiable date object:

```
moment(dateString,'MMM DD YYYY')
```

Next, we want to `diff`erentiate that from now. Like Date, moment assumes now if we pass no argument:

```
moment(dateString,'MMM DD YYYY').diff()
```

We don't want this as a date, but as a duration, so we'll pass it to moment's `duration` method:

```
moment.duration(moment(dateString,'MMM DD YYYY').diff())
```

…and finally, we want this expressed in days:

```
moment.duration(moment(dateString,'MMM DD YYYY').diff()).days()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this:

`$('#Field2').value(calculateDays($('#Field1').toString))` should be like this:

`$('#Field2').value(calculateDays($('#Field1').val()))` or   `$('#Field2').value(calculateDays($('#Field1').text()))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for setting same date in second field.
Link:[jquery: using two datepicker with two fields ( field 1 , field2 + 1 day ) like booking.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219296/jquery-using-two-datepicker-with-two-fields-field-1-field2-1-day-like-b)
Change the format according to your need.

Comment: You just have to do minor changes in this.