# Angularjs bootstrap datepicker: Select multiple dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to use the angular UI strap datepicker. How to select more than one date from the datepicker and return the value as an array.

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker

Comment: I dont see the reason, its not multiple file selection. Can you explain the reason, example. I really never seen something like. DatePIcker supports one date only, and fills textfield

Comment: I think he means something like when booking a vacation on an airline. You can select multiple days. Angular-ui's datePicker does not support this though so @Abre will have to create their own directive.

Comment: yes, something like this.
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If that is what is being asked, then take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219296/jquery-using-two-datepicker-with-two-fields-field-1-field2-1-day-like-b)

Comment: I wrote a module that extends UI Bootstrap's Datepicker to select multiple dates. https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect

Answer (score 3):

You can use gm.datepickerMultiSelect directive, that wraps around ui-bootstrap datepicker directive, adding multi-select feature.

```
<div ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
    <datepicker ng-model='activeDate' multi-select='selectedDates'></datepicker>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['gm.datepickerMultiSelect']);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.activeDate;

    //THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN INITIALIZE VALUES
    $scope.selectedDates = [new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2015, 2, 20).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2015, 2, 10).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2015, 2, 15).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    $scope.removeFromSelected = function (dt) {
        $scope.selectedDates.splice($scope.selectedDates.indexOf(dt), 1);
    }
}
```

There's an article on this on my blog http://irhadbabic.com/?p=351
Also, here's working JSFiddle that you can use http://jsfiddle.net/prdkvp7u/4/

Answer (score 2):

The directive that you're working with doesn't support the multi-datepicker that you want. You can always go for something like [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#multidate) and not necessarily stick with an `Angular` directive.

Your option is fairly limited in this regard unless you customize the directive the way you want it to behave.